# Why do the dielectric caps of parabolic antennas have a metal frame inside?

Tags: dielectric, antennas

Why are the so-called radio-transparent dielectric caps covering parabolic antennas based on a metal frame, which, in theory, will work like a Faraday grid, and if it does not absorb the entire signal, at least significantly attenuate it and create interference due to secondary radiation?

Look inside
[image]
Look outside
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't a window screen stop light? The answer is that when the holes in the structure are much larger than the wavelength of the radiation in question, and occupy most of the area, the structure has little effect on the radiation.

A Faraday cage only has its full effect in a static field. If the wavelength is long compared to the dimensions of the holes in the cage, the field may be considered nearly static. But for shorter wavelengths, you have to shrink the holes.